# Fetch request from xml api and parse repsonse

Tags: xml, reactjs, react-native, xml-parsing, fetch

I'm new to react native and more particularly to fetch request. I fetch a web service who response with an xml file. I tried to parse it and pass the value that I want to a picker but, but it's not working! The response to the request is OK but the problem is in parsing it. I tried the xmldom library and xml12js, nothing worked...

Here it's my code :

```
parseSurface(s){
    const DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
    console.log('Parsing the feed...');
    let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(s, 'text/xml');
    let objs = [];
    let surfs = s.getElementsByTagName('Surfaces');
    //let surfaces = doc.getElementsByTagName('surface:LIBELLE');
     //let surfaces = s.querySelectorAll('Surfaces');
     // let surface = s.querySelectorAll('surface');
     // let libelle = s.querySelector('LIBELLE');
    console.log(surfs)
}

getSurfaces(){
    fetch('myWebService?')
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {
            this.parseSurface(responseText);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error fetching the feed: ', err)
    })

}

componentDidMount(){
    this.getSurfaces();
}
```

In `parseSruface` if I use `doc` variable or `s` I have this error when I input `querySelectorAll` in variable, same with `getElementByTagName` or `getElementByName`:

> Error fetching the feed:  [TypeError: doc.querySelectorAll is not a function. (In 'doc.querySelectorAll('Surfaces')', 'doc.querySelectorAll' is undefined)]

I hope I was clear, I'm totally lost and I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: The `document` object is a representation of a web page. Naturally, React Native doesn't have a `document` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;



getSurfaces(){
    fetch('http://clubonlinetest.alithya.fr/WebServices/AppliMobile.asmx/getSurfaceList?')
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {
            parseString(responseText, function (err, result) {
                console.log(response)
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error fetching the feed: ', err)
    })

}

componentDidMount(){
    this.getSurfaces();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was change the `responseText`with `console.log(result)` and the xml was convert into Json. Now I think arrive to find the value what I looking for in this response.